# Is it decidable if a tree-presented semigroup contains an idempotent?

Tags: gr.group-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

A semigroup presentation $\langle A | R\rangle$ is called tree-like if every relation has the form $ab=c$, $a,b,c$ are in $A$ and if two relations $ab=c, a'b'=c'$ belong to $R$, then $c=c'$ if and only if $a=a'$ and $b=b'$. Example: $P=\langle x | xx=x\rangle$. These presentations correspond to certain *closed* subgroups of the R. Thompson group $F$ (if you are interested, see [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.02572) paper, but the question is purely semigroup theoretic). For example, the presentation $P$ corresponds to $F$ itself.

**Question.** Is it decidable that a semigroup given by a finite tree-like presentation contains an idempotent?

The answer is yes if and only if it is decidable if a closed subgroup of $F$ contains a copy of $F$ (by [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0005105) paper).

Comment: What do you call "closed" subgroup of $F$? there's no occurrence of the word "closed" in your linked paper with Guba.

Comment: It is in the Golan paper, first link. The closure of a subgroup H is the subgroup of piecewise H functions where the endpoints of the pieces are finite diadic - by a result of Golan. Closed subgroups are those which coincide with their closure.

Comment: The connection between closed subgroups and tree-like semigroup presentations: every closed subgroup of $F$ is a diagram group corresponding to a tree-like semigroup presentation.

Comment: And how do you input a "closed" subgroup? in principle there are uncountably any subgroups, so you can't input a subgroup. You can input a finitely generated subgroup by inputting a finite generating subset, but this does not tell you if it's "closed". Or is the set of "closed" subgroups countable with some reasonable enumeration?

Comment: A closure of a f.g. subgroup corresponds to a finitely generated tree-like semigroup presentation. We do not know yet if the closure is f.g. itself, but it is determined by a finite data. So the input is a finite tree-like semigroup presentation.

Comment: Do you have any examples where no word containing at most, say, 3 occurrences of each letter is an idempotent but there are idempotents?  All my examples of idempotents so far don't reuse letters too much.

Comment: $\langle a, b, x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4\mid a=ax_1, x_1=bx_2, x_2=bx_3, x_3=bx_4, x_4=ba\rangle$ implies $a=ab^4a$. Therefore $ab^4$ is an idempotent. I do not think that in this semigroup, there are idempotents with at most 3 $b$'s.

Comment: I agree. I was writing a generic way of getting idempotents but ignored that in my generic way I could reuse letters. I feel like idempotents correspond to cycles in a graph encoding the relations and how left hand and right hand sides overlap and so there must be one not much longer than the number of relations. But maybe there is a more clever way to build idempotents.

Comment: It is possible that a minimal length idempotent cannot be much longer than the size of the presentation.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Old example, but in Mark's example above, the generator $x_1$ is an idempotent, so his claim is not correct.